# Calculate the amount between two dates in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have these 2 tables. I need to merge into one table. Where should I put in the column the amount of expenses between two dates. How can I do it?

Profits:

| Id | Date | Money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2022 | 100 |
| 2 | 15.01.2022 | 50 |
| 3 | 25.01.2022 | 30 |

Expenses:

| Id | Date | Money |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2022 | 20 |
| 2 | 03.01.2022 | 30 |
| 3 | 30.01.2022 | 40 |

Result:

| Id | Date | Profits | Expenses(Sum) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2022 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 15.01.2022 | 50 |  |
| 3 | 25.01.2022 | 30 | 40 |

Comment: Providing data instead of images of it helps to get much faster recommendations from the community.it is one of the reasons that you get Downvote

Comment: what is the logic for for the calculation in your desired table?

Comment: Calculate sum in table Expenses between 2 ordered dates in table Profits and left join this row to table profits

Comment: Your expenses table has a total of 80 Money, but your desired result totals it to 100. Please add an explanation ***(separately for each individual row)*** as to how that row should be calculated.

Comment: Ok. I have table Profits. I get 2 dates 01.01.2022 and 15.01.2022/ Then I summed in the table  Expenses: money between 01.01.2022 and 15.01.2022 and left join row to table Profits. Next I have date 15.01.2022 and 25.01.2022. Summed money in table Expension. Next I have data 25.01.2022 and i summed in the table Expension between 25.01.2022 and 30.01.2022 because table Profits doesn't have last date

Comment: please edit and update your question with the additional information and not in comment. It is hard to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following statement is a possible option:

Data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Profits
FROM (VALUES
   (1, CONVERT(date, '01.01.2022', 104), 100),
   (2, CONVERT(date, '15.01.2022', 104), 50),
   (3, CONVERT(date, '25.01.2022', 104), 30)
) v (Id, [Date], [Money])

SELECT *
INTO Expenses
FROM (VALUES
   (1, CONVERT(date, '01.01.2022', 104), 20),
   (2, CONVERT(date, '03.01.2022', 104), 30),
   (3, CONVERT(date, '30.01.2022', 104), 40)
) v (Id, [Date], [Money])
```

Statement:

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Date, p.Money AS Profits, SUM(e.Money) AS Expenses
FROM (
   SELECT *, LEAD(Date) OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS NextDate
   FROM Profits
) p
LEFT JOIN Expenses e ON p.Date <= e.Date AND (e.Date <= p.NextDate OR p.NextDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Date, p.Money
```

Result:

| Id | Date | Profits | Expenses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 | 50 |
| 2 | 2022-01-15 | 50 |  |
| 3 | 2022-01-25 | 30 | 40 |

For SQL Server 2008 you have to replace `LEAD()` with a self-join (a simplified approach when there are no gaps in the `Id` column):

```
SELECT p.Id, p.Date, p.Money AS Profits, SUM(e.Money) AS Expenses
FROM (
   SELECT p1.*, p2.Date AS NextDate
   FROM Profits p1
   LEFT JOIN Profits p2 ON p1.Id = p2.Id - 1
) p
LEFT JOIN Expenses e ON p.Date <= e.Date AND (e.Date <= p.NextDate OR p.NextDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY p.Id, p.Date, p.Money
```

Comment: I can't run this script because I have MSSql server 2008. Can I replace "Lead" to another syntax? But this script is look cool!

Comment: @Qsandrew, `LEAD()` is available from SQL Server 2012, so you have to use a self join instead (I assume, that there are no gaps in the `Id` column).